# How does StreamReader.ReadToEnd know it's at the end?

Tags: .net, streamreader

[This is a red herring- sorry to waste people's time. Though the info may be useful to someone else.]

I've a custom memory stream that I've wrapped a StreamReader around in order to easily read some text out of it via `ReadToEnd()`. Problem is it never finishes. It's calling my `ReadByte()` function continuously, and any value that can return could be a real value- so unlike with the `Read()` function where I can return zero to indicate the end of data, here I'm stuck. The spec for `ReadByte()` says it returns -1 at the end of data- but that doesn't cause `ReadToEnd()` to stop. It'd be pretty useless if it did.

All I can find in the documentation is *"ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end."* but I don't see how the stream signals that condition.

If `ReadByte()` throws an exception when it gets to the end of the stream, the variable I'm assigning the output to never gets set because the exception isn't caught by the StreamReader. So what condition is it looking for from the stream below it to tell it it's reached the end of the stream?

---

After all the comments and a bit more digging, the problem turned out to be an intermediate stream I'd forgotten about, in which `read()` was calling the substream's `readbyte` and writing the returned data into the array. Thanks to one of the comments, when I discovered that I was able to first read the int into a variable to check whether or not it was an int -1 rather than a byte -1 to decide whether to continue writing to the array or exit because there was no more data.

So the answer to my question is that the signal is a Read() returning zero, and if you see ReadByte being called anywhere then that's the place to start being suspicious.

Comment: You do know that ReadByte returns an `int`, so that -1 is different from any real byte?

Comment: When `Read` returns `0` you're at the end of the stream. I don't get why `ReadByte` gets called at all.

Comment: Yeah. Hadn't explicitly considered that, but my function's declared as `public override int ReadByte()` and I have `if (EndOfInput) return -1;`. Though I've not explicitly marked the -1 as an int, the context sensitive popup identifies it as such. So useful as the distinction may be, it's not being exploited.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The OP is not asking about `Read`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos; yeah but this is `ReadByte()` and I don't think I have control over whether StreamReader calls `Read()` or `ReadByte()`

Comment: Please post code that reproduces the problem. `ReadByte` forwards to `Read` and returns `-1` if `Read` returns `0`. So unless your custom memory stream is broken, it shouldn't matter if `ReadByte` or `Read` gets called.

Comment: @CraigGraham: Looking at [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) (at least the .NET 4.0 version) in ILSpy, I don't see where it - directly or indirectly - would ever call `ReadByte`. Is that a standard `StreamReader` you are using?

Comment: Without code to reproduce the issue we can only offer wild guesses for why your code doesn't work and why `ReadByte` even gets called. `-1` is the correct signal for `ReadByte` and `0` for `Read`.

Comment: How the stream knows its at the end depends entirely upon the stream implementation. Please post yours. Any reason you needed a custom memory stream? Why is a wrapper for the existing MemoryStream class not enough?

Comment: @Gusdor: The question is not about how the *stream* knows it's at the end of the internal *data*, but how the *stream reader* knows it's at the end of the *stream*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. A very simple case doesn't show this, even using my custom stream. So it's not a problem with my stream, nor with StreamReader.ReadToEnd. Sorry to post a red herring.

Comment: @Gusdor; Needed a memory stream that supports one thing writing and another thing reading, rather than one thing writes then the other can seek() back to the start to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to create a custom `Stream` implementation, you should override `Read(byte[], int, int)` instead of `ReadByte()`. The default implementation of `ReadByte()` just calls `Read(buffer, 0, 1)` as a utility method.

The `StreamReader` will call `Read(byte[], int, int)` on the underlying stream. Correctly implement this method to return `0` when the end of the stream is reached to resolve the issue.

Comment: Actually, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx) explain that the default implementation of `ReadByte` is very inefficient and strongly suggest to not only override `Read`, but *also* `ReadByte`.

Comment: Correct. ReadByte is not used by StreamReader AFAIK. Why would it?

Comment: In practice one should override both to improve performance. The default implementation needs to create unnecessary temporary arrays. But I don't get why `ReadByte` matters at all for this question, since AFAIK `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` doesn't call it.

Comment: @usr because you dont want to screw around with a byte[] and you just want one byte?

Comment: @Gusdor `ReadToEnd` by definition screws around with `byte[]`s, it returns one. Using temporary a `byte[]` over `ReadByte` in a `StreamReader` improves performance quite a bit. Using `ReadByte` in `ReadToEnd` would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the code, you'll see that the signal is `Stream.Read` returning 0.

Comment: The question already states that; the OP is asking about the signal by `ReadByte`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. ReadToEnd stops when Read returns zero.